# Set sys_seconds to the epoch i.e. zero

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

Am struggling to find a good way to reset sys_seconds to zero

```
date::sys_seconds st;
//st = date::sys_seconds(0);            //no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to 'date::sys_seconds'
//st = date::sys_seconds{date::sys_seconds(0)}; //no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'int' to 'date::sys_seconds'
//st = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(0);   //no viable overloaded '='
//st = date::sys_seconds(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(0));    //no matching conversion for functional-style cast 
st = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(0)); //works, but verbose
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Your first failure could be a sign that your approach to your [real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) is misguided.

Comment: I get a sys_seconds& parameter from a calling routine and an array of structs from a database table that includes a field holding time_t values.  The routine needs to change the sys_seconds& parameter to the largest time_t value from the database table and hence I want to initialise the sys_seconds& parameter to zero.

Comment: Ah, so you're not interested in "zero" so much as "smallest possible value (which happens to be zero)"? That makes sense. There is at least one other approach to your real problem, but it might lead to this same question depending on what should happen if the database table is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
st = {};
```

Explanation:  The default constructor of `sys_seconds` sets things to zero.  So this just default constructs a `sys_seconds` and assigns it to `st`.  Other ways to do this include:

```
st = date::sys_seconds{};
```

and:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
st = date::sys_seconds{0s};
```